# Request for LINQ query

Tags: linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have a sql query. Please someone help me to convert it into LINQ.

```
select * from ProductOrder where OrderId != (Select OrderId from OrderEvents) and MemberId=2
```

I write this code. But tis is not working. please help me.

```
                              from order in db.ProductOrder
                              from cancel in db.OrderEvents
                              where order.MemberId == MemberId 
                              where order.OrderId != cancel.OrderId 
                              //orderby order.OrderId descending 
                              select order
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: You missed my point. You need to show what you have already tried. At least demonstrate some effort. Stack Overflow is not here to write code for you.

Comment: @JonB:: I upload my code. please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProductOrder.Where(x=>x.OrderId != OrderEvents.OrderId && x.MemberId ==2)
```